# Please explain prototypes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand javascript prototypes at a more fundamental level.

The first log makes sense as clearly its an instance of Vehicle. However if log two is false, and Vehicle.prototype is not an instance of Vehicle why does the final log show Vehicle{} indicating an instance of Vehicle?

```
class Vehicle {
  constructor() {
    console.log("created Vehicle instance");
  }
}
const vehicle = new Vehicle();

console.log(vehicle instanceof Vehicle);
console.log(Vehicle.prototype instanceof Vehicle);
console.log(typeof Vehicle.prototype);
console.log(Vehicle.prototype);
```

Comment: You might want to check out [MDN's article on prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) to see if that answers your question.

Comment: *"why does the final log show Vehicle{} indicating an instance of Vehicle?"* There is no standard for printing objects in the console, so browsers can do *whatever they want*. The fact that you see `Vehicle {}` doesn't mean anything.  In Chrome I see `{constructor: f}`, in Firefox I see `Object { … }` . Presumably the environment your running the code in prints whatever `value.constructor.name` is.

Comment: Instances inherit a `constructor` property from their consructor's prototype property. Its default value is the contsructor function itself. This is what you are seeing in the last log - an object with a property named "constructor".

Comment: Thanks Felix I was also wondering why when I used the vs code debugger I was getting different types too. This clears that up.

Comment: Is the prototype a singleton? Prototypes hang off of the object constructor, MyFunc.prototype but they aren't static because they have access to the instance via this and its properties. And it's shared across object instances. So it feels like a singleton.